# SSL/TLS issue with Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to run `curl` command in PowerShell but I am facing error that I am not able to connect SSL/TLS

```
$loginurl= https://education.org/logon
$data= New-Object "System.collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$data.Add('username','abc')
$data.Add('password','abc')
$method=POST
$response= Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Uri $loginurl -Body $data

$response.RawContent
```

I tried writing in Shell it worked but in shell I used `--insecure-sS` as another switch to work. Can anyone please help how to resolve this in PowerShell and sometimes it gives me syntax error as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `-SkipCertificateCheck` switch:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Uri $loginurl -Body $data -SkipCertificateCheck
```

Incidentally, a simpler way to create your hashtable is like this:

```
$data = @{'username'='abc';'password'='abc'}
```